# array manipulation using pointers in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

The following code generates random nums betw 1-9 to fill in a 3x3 array. I can generate the numbers, but when I try to dereference my array pointer and assign the numbers to elements in the 3x3 array, my program crashes. It compiles and runs if I comment out the line that does the assignment. Can someone explain the error?

```
void initSquare(MagSquare_PTR mptr, int magicsquaresize){
int i, j, k, m, randomNum, hasRepeat, numSquares, checkCount,whileCount;
numSquares = (magicsquaresize * magicsquaresize);
int check[numSquares][2];
for(m = 0; m < numSquares; m++){
    check[m][0] = m;
    check[m][1] = 0;
}

for( i = 0; i < magicsquaresize; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < magicsquaresize; j++){
        randomNum = ((rand()%numSquares) + 1);
        while(check[randomNum-1][1] == 1){
            randomNum = ((rand()%numSquares) + 1);
        }
        check[randomNum-1][1] = 1;
        //*mptr[i][j] = randomNum;//THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE
        printf("%d", randomNum); //test
    }
}
```

}

Comment: instead of doing this you can keep track of occurence in a `frequency array` which is initially initialized to `0`and if the frequency becomes greater than `0` then that element shouldn't be inserted

Comment: Try to simplify your code. For example, you don't really need *two* outer `for` loops, and then you don't need a separate `checkCount` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if not statically declared, you must insure that memory has been allocated to hold your array values you reference with mptr. If you allocate memory for your array, it is a good idea to allocate with `calloc` so that all array values are initialized to `0`. A simple function to initialize a 2 dimensional array declared as int **myarray could use the following:

```
float **array_calloc (int rows, int cols)
{
    register int i;
    float **array = xmalloc (rows * sizeof (*array));

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        array [i] = xcalloc (cols, sizeof (**array));
    }
    return array;
}
```

In the main() body, you can utilize the function as:

```
int **myarray;
myarray = array_calloc (3, 3);
```

After initializing, you can fill your array as follows:

```
for (rows = 0; rows < 3; rows++)
{
    for (cols = 0; cols < 4; cols++)
        myarray [rows][cols] = yourvalue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some odd things...

```
k = numSquares;
```

I bet the only purpose of that is to stop the loop?
Use:

```
break;
```

instead. That will make your code more clear.

You don't need to be executing the else all the time.
You can simply say:

```
 hasRepeat = 0;
```

right after you enter the while loop.

After you leave the while loop you have this:

```
checkCount++;
printf("%d", randomNum);
```

What line of code do you expect to be executed after this printf? I bet it is not this:

```
checkCount = 0;
```

What would be the point of increment and set to 0 right after? I think you meant initialize it somewhere else...

And last but not least: there are easier ways to get this hashtable behavior that you meant as some people suggested in comments